# Running a script in cmd.exe works fine, but when I run it in a 3rd party shell or IDE it does not work

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

Windows 7 64-bit.

Running the bog-standard windows command shell (on my system this lives here: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`) I can a simple lua script, below is the output:

```
D:\user\workspace\_lua>lua yamltest.lua
Lua Version: 5.1
doc_path = d:\user
Found file: .
Found file: ..
Found file: downloads
Found file: install
Found file: My Network Area.lnk
Found file: mybin
Found file: personal
Found file: sandbox
Found file: starter_stuff
Found file: tasks.csv
Found file: workspace
loading yaml...
yaml loaded: mytest.yaml
end
................
```

However, when I run this using a different command shell, like consoleZ (console 2) or ConEmu, I get errors when I run exactly the same command. Like this:

```
D:\user\workspace\_lua>lua yamltest.lua
Lua Version: 5.1
doc_path = d:\user
Found file: .
Found file: ..
Found file: downloads
Found file: install
Found file: My Network Area.lnk
Found file: mybin
Found file: personal
Found file: sandbox
Found file: starter_stuff
Found file: tasks.csv
Found file: workspace
d:\user\install\lua\luarocks\lua.exe: error loading module 'yaml.core' from file 'D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5
        Invalid access to memory location.
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...all\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\yaml\init.lua:26: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        yamltest.lua:13: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

This appears to be a runtime issue - when I ran the command through an IDE I got the same output, but also a window like this:

[image]

I have tried a whole pile of things to find out what the difference could be...

- 64-bit vs 32-bit: no, I run cmd-64 and cmd-32 both work fine. I also installed 64/32-bit versions of the shells and tried both, both fail.
- Different cmd.exe called?: no, I configured ConEmu to explicitly run `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`, still failed.
- Environment Vars: No, I printed the vars for ConEmu and cmd.exe. ConEmu had a bunch of ConEmu vars and an extra path to ConEmu install... but none of these have anything that (as far as I can see) could effect the running of an application.
- Run as admin: no, I ran all variants as admin / normal user - still, every cmd.exe instance works and every shell fails.
- Issues piping via cmd.exe /c ?: no, I tried this within a bat file and ran it from the windows run bar.... worked fine.

What can be the issue here? - I really can't see what the difference possibly is? - but there is clearly some difference between the two methods...

Comment: This indeed looks weird, especially since you observe it with Console 2 too. How about creating an intermediate process, i.e. in both consoles, you first open a *new* command shell (CMD), and run the program in it. Still no change in behaviour?

Comment: Its a good idea.. I did `start call c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe` from within ConEmu to start the cmd.exe. But when I ran my script it failed still :(

Comment: And if you just execute `cmd` (without any parameters), and **then** `lua yamltest.lua`? From the error, my guess is that there is something broken in the C program which hosts lua (like a stray pointer or so), and that this error just by accident doesn't show up in the normal Windows console. Also worth trying would be to install Cygwin and run it from a, say, mintty console.

Comment: BTW, in your command `start call c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe`, the *call* doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This does not work either :(  ... hmm, the "start call" I found on a SO post - I wanted it to start cmd.exe in a new window to divorce it from ConEmu,

Comment: I'm not that much a Windows expert, but I know `call` in the context of *invoking one batch file from another one*. In any case, I would give it one more try in the context of Cygwin+mintty, but otherwise it looks more and more like a bug in Lua, which just happens to not show in a normal Windows console (that's why nobody had noticed before), so you could open a bug issue agains Lua.